# how to detect if a particular form option is selected based on it's value or ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

i'm having a helluva time ascertaining the value of a checked radio button of a form and can't figure out why. this form has many radio buttons (options), maybe 50 or more. each option represents a color swatch. Note, the radio buttons themselves are not shown  but is replaced instead with a color swatch image (maybe this is causing problems with the js).

there is a default option, and i need to run some code based on if the user has either selected this option or made no selection at all.

the markup for a swatches option looks like this.

```
<div class="threads-swatch-wrapper">
<input type="radio" name="id[9]" value="89" id="attrib-9-89" class="threads-radio-btn" />
<label class="attribsRadioButton two thread-opts" for="attrib-9-89">SL55<br />
  <img src="images/attributes/SL55.jpg" alt="" width="260" height="320" />
</label></div>
```

the default option has no swatch image and looks like this
    
        
        Please Select

the pseudo code would read something like:

```
if($('#color-swatches option:selected value = 182')) <!-- this the default --> {
    'run some code';
} else {
    'run some other code';
}
```

i've tried setting variables but they keep coming up undefined!

```
selected_val = $( "input:radio[name=id]:checked" ).val(); //undefined
```

Comment: Why are you using `option:selected` - that's for a `select` element - use `.val()` on radio buttons. Also, not seeing anything with the ID of `color-swatches`

Comment: Where is your `<select>` tag?

Comment: Change your selector to `"input[type="radio"][name^="id"]:checked"`

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there - you just need to change your selector to check for names *starting with* `id` not equal to it. To do this, use the [starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) - `name^=id`:

```
selected_val = $( "input:radio[name^=id]:checked" ).val();
if(selected_val == '182') {
    // run some code
} else {
    // run some other code
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/468crack/1/)